# Multi-view PDF reader (support for multiple screen views)

Tags: macbook-pro, pdf

I have two screens connected to my mac, and I would like to see different pages of the same PDF on each screen. Does Preview support this? If not, what alternatives do I have in OS X?

Comment: The open command in Terminal could open a 2nd instance- you could then open the same PDF in each.

Comment: @Tetsujin -- That doesn't work for me. I tried both (1) opening a new instance of the same PDF through the terminal and (2) opening a different PDF also through the terminal, and later going through the menu of Preview to open the PDF I want to see. In both cases, Preview brought to focus the only one instance I had already opened and I ended up with only one view.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any PDF viewer which can have the same document open in two windows.

A workaround would be to use Acrobat for the main work, and Preview for "reference", accepting that Preview may not have write rights for the document.